# Purpose of string in front of maketrans

Tags: python, string, dictionary

What is the purpose of the string in front of `maketrans` when all these codes output the same result?

```
'abc'.maketrans('abc','wty')
'wty'.maketrans('abc','wty')
''.maketrans('abc','wty')
'anything you like GH5641567sdfsd'.maketrans('abc','wty')

#{97: 119, 98: 116, 99: 121}
```

On the other hand using without the string gives error:

```
maketrans('abc','wty')
```

All the examples in documentation seems to use it this way:

```
s1.maketrans(s1,s2)
```

But why when the first occurence of string `s1` seems to be irrelevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`maketrans` is a [static method](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.maketrans), meaning it really should be called using the class `str` like this (to avoid confusion):

```
str.maketrans
```

and calling it with a `str` instance (literal or not), such as `'hello'.maketrans`, the `'hello'` doesn't really affect the execution of the static method `maketrans`, because it doesn't get passed to the method, so, actually, `maketrans` doesn't even know what the string that called it is.

Comment: What the `str` stands for in `str.maketrans`? Why all the examples seems to use some string instead of `str` when there is no point in doing so? Does it affect the time of execution when a string is used instead of `str`?

Comment: @azerbajdzan What examples?

Comment: Say https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_maketrans.asp, but there are lots of similar.

Comment: @azerbajdzan First, I wouldn't recommend w3schools for serious learning, second, it doesn't really matter how you call `maketrans`, either `str.maketrans` or `'hi'.maketrans`, it is the same output, because the method doesn't care what called it, but it is not uncommon that people use instances to call static methods.

Comment: @azerbajdzan In older version of Python (2.x and probably up to 3.1, not sure exactly), `maketrans` was available through the `string` module, now it is readily available through the `str` class.